# How to show the convergence of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $a_n$ which converges to the limit $l$, how do I show the convergence of the sequence $b_n=a_{n+1}$ using $\epsilon$-definition of convergence of a sequence? I know that $b_n$ will also converge to the same limit $l$ and this is how I tried to show it. Given $\epsilon > 0$, since $a_n$ is convergent there exists some natural number $N$ such that-
$$ |a_n-l|<\epsilon  $$
$\forall n>N.$ Now replacing $n$ by $n+1$, we get-
$$|a_{n+1}-l|<\epsilon$$
$\forall n>N-1$. So we can say that the sequence $b_n$ converges to $l$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Well it's automated won't it, $a_n$ converge to a limit $l$ Then suppose not and achive a contradiction!!! It works because $a_n$ is cauchy!!!